# castle-windsor - return different implementation according to call against another component

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I'm creating a web API and I want to be able to version it. The way I want to do it is this:

1. Client application passes in custom HTTP header with each request containing version
   of API they're calling against.
2. A component (called `IVersionRetriever` or something) exists to pull
   the version number from the request. Castle Windsor is responsible
   for providing instances of `IVersionRetriever`.
3. Where I want the implementation of a service interface to vary
   between versions, Castle Windsor is configured to check
   `IVersionRetriever.ApiVersion` and return an implementation
   according to the value obtained.

All this seems simple enough, but I can't work out from Windsor's registration API how I would say to Windsor 'right, for `IFoo`, if `IVersionRetriever.ApiVersion` is 1, then I want a `SuperFoo`, but if the version is 2, then I want a `SuperDuperFoo`.

How would I configure this?

All components have a PerWebRequest lifestyle, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so you know how to do it in the future:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IUnitOfWork>().UsingFactoryMethod(() => IVersionRetriever.ApiVersion == 1 ? new SuperFoo() : new SuperDuperFoo() ).LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
```

but i agree with @Cristiano answer.

Comment: Don't I need to actually get the `IVersionRetriever` instance from the container before making calls on it?

Comment: change it to () => container.Resolve<IVersionRetriever >().ApiVersion == 1

Answer (score 2):

What about using a TypedFactory to resolve the desired IFoo according to ApiVersion? In that case dependency won't be on IFoo, but on IFooFactory instead